# How do I get the user name of the user profile page that is being visited?

Tags: 7, users

I created a module and I need to use the user name of the user's profile being viewed.

How do I call/get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load a user object like this :

```
$current_user = menu_get_object('user', 1);
$username = $current_user->name;
```

Reference of [menu_get_object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) function.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the user that's currently visiting your website that your looking to display then this code can be used.

```
 global $user;
 print $user->name;
```